# How to hide current ViewController in the transition animation when presenting a new view controller

Tags: ios, swift

I try to do a redirect process when I click the button on ViewController - VC1.

Redirect flow is like: VC1 -> VC2 -> VC3

I present VC3 in viewDidAppear() or viewWillAppear() of VC2.

But I still saw VC2 during the transition animation.

Does anyone have an idea for hiding VC2 during transition animation?

And App can come back to VC2 when VC3 is dismissed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you're already on V1 and trying to push to V3. You can do something like this:

```
private func gotoThirdController() {
    guard var controllers = self.navigationController?.viewControllers else { return }
    let secondController = SecondController()
    let thridController = ThirdController()

    controllers.append(secondController)
    controllers.append(thridController)
    self.navigationController?.setViewControllers(controllers, animated: true)
}
```